How to send a message between agents (to a specific state chart transition) while the agents are in the same class in Anylogic
I have four agents in the main of an Anylogic's model, as seen in the photo, in each agent I have a state chart, and in one of the transitions I want to send a message to another agent (neighbor agent not parent), in the same class as they are both in the main, meaning that I want to send a message from a transition in the compressor agent to the transport agent saying "system failure" and then from the transport agent back to the compressor agent.


I tried the following trials:

I first used the usual command "send ("System Failure", transport);", and it gave an error that the "transport" can't be resolved to a variable.
I used one of the commands I found here "sendToAllConnected(transport);", and still the error persists.
I tried the "Link Between Agents" and it kept the same error.
I looked it up on YouTube and I found nothing new.
I tried the "sendToAllConnected("SystemFailure" - it did not give any error in the "Problem View" but it gave an error in the Console view
I tried "send("SystemFailure", main.transport(i).transition1" - I don't know if that code right I took it from the Anylogic help but it was for a parameter, not a state chart.
I can't put them as "parent/child" agents as I need them connected to the main as they are directly affecting a system dynamic model in the main agent and it can't work when there is an agent in between.


Check this out and try to solver your problem in a (much) simpler example model with dummy agents: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Believe it or not, this is as simple as it could ever get :), the system is much more complex, I did check this with Anylogic's help, and I tried to use it to create a code of my own but it didn't help, the only option that did help and gave no errors on the "Problems view" was the (sendToAllConnected("System Failure"), but still it gave an error on the Console view, and that's the one I'm sharing here

It could get much simpler, believe me :) But thx for the effort

Your question is ambiguous, some suggestions:

Send from 1 compressor agent to another (say from compressor agent #3 to #1):
main.compressor.get(1).myCompressorStateChart.fireEvent("myMessage")

Send from 1 compressor agent to a transport agent (say from compressor agent #3 to transport agent #1):
main.transport.get(1).myTransportStateChart.fireEvent("myMessage")

Send from 1 tranport agent to a compressor agent (say from tranport agent #1 to compressor agent #3):
main.compressor.get(3).myCompressorStateChart.fireEvent("myMessage")



So Jasmine khattab at the end you are just simply a programmer ! So you get it faster or you just used online a language that mainly a programmer using and that is illegal because the programmer must not abused the online this way or Google company will hire programmers and do same what you did right !?? Anyway why you are running awake from the police ! They are searching for you since the day you stole my private properties and added to them my intellectual properties,I advice you to go to the police and surrounded yourself and say the truth about my sisters , my mother and the king and queen of Jordan and their kids specially the oldest son and how they are torturing me via you and even you torturing me via them from inside to outside my body that caused me so much pain 24/7 and destroyed my look and shape .anyhow Bye bye

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
